# Give multiple arguments to a function

Tags: python, string, function, arguments

i want to give multiple arguments to a functions from a string
for example if i have a function

```
def myfunc(x, y, z):
       return x*y+z
```

How do i give it arguments from a string like '1, 2, 3',
I want something like this

```
def myfunc(x, y, z):
       return x*y+z

string = '1, 2, 3'

myfunc(string)
```

Comment: if a string is the argument you want to be passing to the function make the conversion inside the function rather than outside.

Answer (score 2):

`'1, 2, 3'` is a string representation of a tuple of ints.  A simple way to handle that is to use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) which allows you to "*safely evaluate* an expression node or a string containing ... the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and `None`":

```
import ast
s = '1, 2, 3'
tup_of_int = ast.literal_eval(s) # converts '1, 2, 3' to (1, 2, 3)
myfunc(*tup_of_int) # unpack items from tup_of_int to individual function args
```

The code can be written on one line like so:

```
myfunc(*ast.literal_eval(s))
```

For more information about how the asterisk in `myfunc(*tup_of_int)` works see [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) from [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

**Note:**  Do not be tempted to `eval` in place of `ast.literal_eval`.  `eval` is [really dangerous because it cannot safely handle untrusted input](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), so you should not get comfortable using it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the last line with `myfunc(*map(int, string.split(',')))`.

`string.split(',')` splits the string into a list of the three arguments.

`map(int, string.split(','))` converts the elements of the list to integers.

`myfunc(*map(int, string.split(',')))` [`splats`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/3901060) the list so that the three elements of the list get passed as parameters.

This method relies on your input having the exact format as shown in your example string (`'1,2,3'` would not work). Steven's response is more robust so I recommend going with that one.

Comment: this passes strings to the function. You have to map them to integers or floats.

Comment: `int` will happily handle `' 2'` (with a preceding space) so you can make your code more robust by splitting on a comma only instead of space+comma.  This means that if the input becomes `'1,2, 3'` the code will still work.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thank you, I didn't realize `int` could parse the spaces. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for your problem:
First of all you have to split the string then proceed to next step:

```
def myfunc(x, y, z):
   return x * y + z

a=raw_input()
x,y,z=map(int,a.split(","))
print myfunc(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score -1):

One liner (*although parsing string arguments like this could introduce vulnerabilities in your code*).

```
>>> myfunc(*eval(string))  # myfunc((1, 2, 3))
5
```

Comment: Why recommend `eval` when `ast.literal_eval` exists?  It's like recommending someone use a handgun for a flyswatter.  Even with a disclaimer it's a bad idea.

Comment: Hmm, thought my disclaimer made it clear that this could be a potentially dangerous implementation. I think your statement is certainly fair. But to not show potential approaches at all seems like a self-imposed limitation to understanding a problem truly. @StevenRumbalski